When I click on a check box it only selects the top check box
I will click on any checkbox, and it will only selects the top one.
These checkboxes can be deleted or added. When I add one that isn't yet saved in the database, it properly selects the checkbox. But if I want to click on one that is already in the database to delete that row, it does not select it but instead selects the top row checkbox.
    `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {           
        $(".itemRow").prop("checked", this.checked);
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '.itemRow', function() {    
        if ($('.itemRow:checked').length == $('.itemRow').length) {
            $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });  
    var count = $(".itemRow").length;
    $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
        count++;
        var htmlRows = '';
        htmlRows += '<tr>';
        htmlRows += '<td><div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input itemRow" id="itemRow_'+count+'"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="itemRow_'+count+'"></label> </div></td>';          
        htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
        htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>'; 
        htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';        
        htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';      
        htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
        htmlRows += '</tr>';
        $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRows', function(){
        $(".itemRow:checked").each(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
        calculateTotal();
    });     
    $(document).on('blur', "[id^=quantity_]", function(){
        calculateTotal();
    }); 
    $(document).on('blur', "[id^=price_]", function(){
        calculateTotal();
    }); 
    $(document).on('blur', "#taxRate", function(){      
        calculateTotal();
    }); 
    $(document).on('blur', "#amountPaid", function(){
        var amountPaid = $(this).val();
        var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();  
        if(amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
            totalAftertax = totalAftertax-amountPaid;           
            $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
        } else {
            $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
        }   
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteInvoice', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?")){
            $.ajax({
                url:"action.php",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{id:id, action:'delete_invoice'},              
                success:function(response) {
                    if(response.status == 1) {
                        $('#'+id).closest("tr").remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}); 
function calculateTotal(){
    var totalAmount = 0; 
    $("[id^='price_']").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("price_",'');
        var price = $('#price_'+id).val();
        var quantity  = $('#quantity_'+id).val();
        if(!quantity) {
            quantity = 1;
        }
        var total = price*quantity;
        $('#total_'+id).val(parseFloat(total));
        totalAmount += total;           
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(parseFloat(totalAmount));    
    var taxRate = $("#taxRate").val();
    var subTotal = $('#subTotal').val();    
    if(subTotal) {
        var taxAmount = subTotal*taxRate/100;
        $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount);
        subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal)+parseFloat(taxAmount);
        $('#totalAftertax').val(subTotal);      
        var amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
        var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();  
        if(amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
            totalAftertax = totalAftertax-amountPaid;           
            $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
        } else {        
            $('#amountDue').val(subTotal);
        }
    }
}

 

<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input itemRow" id="itemRow">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="itemRow"></label>
                                </div></td>`

I've looked through everything; what am I missing?
